# Why I'm getting network unavailable, sleeping when I try to post some data to a firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating an app and at every Post Request I make to the Firebase Database it throws me this error

```
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/*********/o
    java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
        at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:492)
        at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:552)
        at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1180)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:405)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequestStart(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:250)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:270)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:103)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:467)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:216)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.0:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I added my SHA-1 KEY to the Firebase console, but still the same. 
Funny fact that yesterday when I made the project it was working.
I google the error and the solutions were to add 'firebase auth ' in the build.gradle , but I do have already those implementations:

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this or at least give me some information to understand what I have to do to handle this? Thank you!

Database Rules

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {

      allow read, write;

    }

  }

}
```

Storage Rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after uninstalling the app and reinstalling it again 
I hope you have added the required permissions.